# Best electronic components finder software

Tags: digital-logic, components

I want know what is the best electronic components finder software? That has these features;

1. Easy to find components such as transitor, ICs and so on
2. If we type 10bit ac to dc converter, I want ICs part numbers and datasheets
3. Components with datasheet and pin-out and so on
4. Components categories with company or family

Comment: I wonder what kind of IC a 10 bit ac to dc converter is...

Comment: Digikey has my favorite search engine.

Answer (score 4):

I don´t think there is a "best software/website", you will need to look at websites like distributors/manufactors for this. There are some very helpfull websites like:

[Octopart](https://octopart.com/)

[Parts.io](http://parts.io/)

Also, [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/) and [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/) are great places to find parts.

Hope it helps!